# Novel where the protagonist travels through time (and space?) to an environment he cannot escape from, and encounters his much older self

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel

I am seeking the title (and author) of a novel whose chief character travels through time (and space?) to a place where he is alone in a large environment but cannot escape from it. At one stage he glimpses another distant person but cannot make contact. It eventually turns out that the other person is himself, much older, still trapped in the same situation.

I read the book many years ago and would like to find it again to re-read.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this book, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot recall exactly when I read it, although I am sure it was before 2000 and after about 1975. I do not remember any cover design; I think it was a single novel in the book, rather than in an anthology. Apologies that this is not very helpful!